# Convert ReadableStream to a String and then back to a ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am using the fetch api to get some data. At a more general point, I want to add data to all responses.  So I want to parse the body of an Response object, add the data and rebuild an Response Object, that has again a ReadableStream in its body.

something like this:

```
fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        var cpyResponse = response.clone();
        console.log(cpyResponse.text());
        return response.blob()
    }
    )
    .then(blob => { return new Response(blob) })
    .then(response => {
        var cpyResponse = response.clone();
        console.log(cpyResponse.text());
        return response;
    }
    )
```

this somehow does not work. The second response is broken.

Comment: `new Response(counter, { status: 200, })` - I want to convert `counter:number` to a `ReadableStream`